# How can I efficiently concatenate two nested ForiegnKey relationships?

Tags: python, django, django-models

In a Django 2.2 model, I have the following setup:

```
class Kiosk(Model):
    newspapers = ForeignKey('Newspaper')

class Newspaper(Model):
    articles = ForeignKey('Article')

class Article(Model):
    pass
```

Now, I can get all articles of one newspaper sold in a kiosk like so:

```
kiosk = Kiosk.objects.first()
articles = kiosk.newspapers.first().articles
```

What I want to do is get one QuerySet (or RelatedManager) spanning all articles in all newspapers sold by a kiosk.

I can of course achieve this by iterating over the newspapers and concatenating the articles lists in a for loop, but that seems inefficient.

How can I get this from the ORM?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to start from Article.

```
articles = Article.objects.filter(newspaper__kiosk=my_kiosk)
```

Comment: Just to clarify. In order to be able to do this, `Article` class must have a `ForeignKey` field called `newspaper`; `Newspaper` class must have a `ForeignKey` field called `kiosk`; and `Kiosk` doesn't need any `ForeignKey` for this.